# how to Implement the option of choosing product weight on drop down option

Tags: category, product-list

[image][image: i want to same like this option to display in my website]

i want to display as like above image in my website in product list page.

Comment: You want show product weight and price ?? Can you share Magento version as well

Comment: yes i am using version 1.9.2

Answer (score 0):

Go to custom options tab on the product manage section.. add options with input type 'dropdown'. You can also add configurable product for this.

More details on http://insync.co.in/how-to-create-custom-options-configurable-products-in-magento/

Then add following code in your catalog/product/list.phtml after  line:

```
<?php
     //$productSku = $_product->getSku();
     //$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
     //$productId = $product->getIdBySku( $productSku );
     $product = Mage::getModel("catalog/product")->load($_product->getId());
     $attVal = $product->getOptions();
     $optStr = "";
?>
```

Replace  with following code in same page.

```
<div class="actions">
<?php if($_product->isSaleable()):?>
 <form action="<?php echo $this->helper('checkout/cart')->getAddUrl($_product)?>" method="post" id= "product_addtocart_form" <?php if($_product->getOptions()):?> enctype="multipart/form-data"<?php endif;?>>
<div style='float: left; width: 100px;'>
 <?php foreach($attVal as $optionKey => $optionVal)
{
     $optStr.= "<select style='display:block; clear:both;' name='options[".$optionVal->getId()."]'>";           foreach($optionVal->getValues() as $valuesKey => $valuesVal)
{
      $optStr.= "<option value='".$valuesVal->getId()."'>".$valuesVal->getTitle()."</option>";
}
$optStr.= "</select>";
}
echo($optStr );?>

 <!--Change click action in button -->
 <button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?>" class="button btn-cart" onclick="this.form.submit();"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></span></span></button>
</div>
<?php else:?>
     <p class="availability out-of-stock"><span><?php echo $this->__('Out of stock')?></span></p>
 <?php endif;?>
<ul class="add-to-links">
<?php if ($this->helper('wishlist')->isAllow()) :?>
<li>
     <a href="<?php echo $this->helper('wishlist')->getAddUrl($_product)?>" class="link-wishlist">
            <?php echo $this->__('Add to Wishlist')?>
     </a>
</li>
<?php endif;?>
<?php if($_compareUrl=$this->getAddToCompareUrl($_product)):?>
<li>
     <span class="separator">|</span>
     <a href="<?php echo $_compareUrl?>" class="link-compare"><?php echo $this->__('Add to     Compare')?>
     </a>
</li>
<?php endif;?>
</ul>
 </form>
 </div>
```

Comment: thank you, but i want to option show in product list page like than image

Comment: i update my answer check now

Comment: not working this code